# Trying to upload a file to slack chanel and getting either "invalid_form_data" or "no_file_data" error

Tags: java, multipartform-data, slack, slack-api, apache-commons

Trying to upload a file. I have to use apache-http, because it's used in our codebase.

If I'm providing file as `byte[]` to `builder.addBinaryBody` - I'm getting `invalid_form_data` error in response, with either `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` or `DEFAULT_BINARY` content type.

If providing as `File` - same, `invalid_form_data`.

If as `FileInputStream(file)` -  getting `no_file_data`.

```
public void sendFile(file) throws Exception {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://slack.com/api/files.upload");
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType());

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addBinaryBody(
            "file",
            FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file), // or just file, or new InputFileStream(file)
            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, // or DEFAULT_BINARY
            "file.txt"
    );

    request.setEntity(builder.build());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Response: " + responseString); 
    // either {"ok":false,"error":"invalid_form_data"} or {"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}
}
```

What am I donig wrong?